# reverse Video: Moviepy Error, by using time.mirror

Tags: python, ffmpeg, moviepy, ffmpeg-python

im desperately trying to reverse a movie with moviepy by using .time_mirror.

```
from moviepy.editor import *
import moviepy.video.fx.all as vfx
# Load the video
video = VideoFileClip("/videos/uncut/videogames/other/001.mp4")


popreversed_video = video.fx(vfx.time_mirror)

# Save the reversed video
reversed_video.write_videofile("videos/cut/videogames/other/001_rev.mp4")

print("done")
```

but im always getting this error:

```
MoviePy error: failed to read the first frame of video file /videos/uncut/videogames/other/001.mp4. That might mean that the file is corrupted. That may also mean that you are using a deprecated version of FFMPEG. On Ubuntu/Debian for instance the version in the repos is deprecated. Please update to a recent version from the website.
  File "/Shorts Project/codefiles/video_play_and_rewinde_test_001.py", line 11, in <module>
    popreversed_video = video.fx(vfx.time_mirror)
OSError: MoviePy error: failed to read the first frame of video file /videos/uncut/videogames/other/001.mp4. That might mean that the file is corrupted. That may also mean that you are using a deprecated version of FFMPEG. On Ubuntu/Debian for instance the version in the repos is deprecated. Please update to a recent version from the website.
```

the funny thing is, moviepy is installed, uninstalled, reinstalled and updated.
further, ffmpeg is installed, uninstalled, reinstalled, updated.

but stimm its not working.

Please help

Thank you

- pip install moviepy
- pip uninstall moviepy
- pip install ffmpeg
- pip install ffmpeg-python
- brew install ffmpeg
- pip uninstall ffmpeg
- pip install --upgrade moviepy

probably not in this order, but everything is on the currently newest version.
Operator: MacOs

Answer (score 0):

The problem has only been fixed on the pre-release version.

You can install it via pip with the "--pre" switch

**Example install:**

```
pip install moviepy --pre
```

*see [this comment on github](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/pull/1220#issuecomment-704270019) for more information.*

Comment: Keep in mind this pre release may break other parts of the code.
In my case the ffmpeg_extract_subclip() function did not give the same behaviour.